# Get bool value of Checkbox in wpf with binding in mvvm C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have the following code:

ViewModel:

```
DownloadDeviceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool isSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        if(isSelected)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="Checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding isSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The method onPropertyChanged is in the ViewModelBase. I have not inserted this to make it easier to read.

Every time when I call the value of "isSelected" in a method, IsSelected returns wrong. 
Even though I selected the checkbox and the value of isSelected was set to true.

But in the method the value changes back to false.

What did I implement incorrectly that the value is always changed to false?

Thank you all

Comment: Make sure you set your xaml's `DataContext` to the instance of `DownloadDeviceViewModel` that you're working with.

Comment: Yes I have set my DataContext.

Comment: Is PropertyChanged properly implemented?

Comment: Try `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(isSelected))`

Answer (score 0):

your ViewModel needs to be `INotifyPropertyChanged` :

```
DownloadDeviceViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
    }
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool isSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("isSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        if(isSelected)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, `UpdateSourceTrigger` is no needed

```
<CheckBox Content="Checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding isSelected}"/>
```

is enough

Comment: The method NotifyPropertyChanged is already in the ViewModelBase. I have not listed it here because it would be too much code.

Comment: @Max so I guess you have an error on `ViewModelBase`, because for me it works perfectly, check that when you check/uncheck the CheckBox, that you go through `NotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score -3):

In your setter, remove the "if" conditional, you don't need it. That might be causing your problems.

```
        set
        {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
        }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help. 
The if condition only applies if the current state of the checkbox does not differ from the wanted value. e.g. if I have a button "Select all". Then I do not need to fire OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: Did you make sure you set your DataContext to your ViewModel?

Comment: Yes I have set my DataContext.

Comment: Max, your posted code is just a hair away from being a complete sample project.  I highly suggest that you isolate your problem into a new project containing just the Checkbox, your view model, and your ViewModelBase.  If the problem persists, then post your MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.cs, and your ViewModelBase.  Based on what you've posted, there is nothing visibly wrong.  Therefore, the problem could be in the areas that you didn't post.

Comment: Tam Bui I guess the problem lies in the MainWindow.
I guess I have the binding to the custom control wrong and this causes a second thread to be created when I query the bool. 
I will try to make my MainWindow straight.